# Given $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $P(A_n)\geq \epsilon$ for all n, does it follow that there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ s.t. $P(\cap_kA_{n_k})>0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is problem 4.21b of *A Probability Path* by Resnick.

#### Suppose $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of events. Show the following is false: Given $\epsilon>0$ such that $P(A_n)\geq \epsilon$, it follows that there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ tending to infinity such that  $P(\cap_kA_{n_k})>0$.

I have no idea of this problem. Could anyone give a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a usual independent coin-toss with uniform probability. Then we define $\Omega := \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $$A_n := \{\omega=(\omega_1,\dots, \omega_k, \dots) \in \Omega : \omega_n = \omega_{n+1} = 0 \}$$
We have $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = \frac{1}{4}$. Let $(A_{n_k})_k$ a subsequence of $(A_n)_n$. Then consider $(n_{\phi(k)})_k$ subsequence of $(n_k)_k$ such that $n_{\phi(k+1)} - n_{\phi(k)} >1$. Then $$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_k A_{n_k}\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_k A_{n_{\phi(k)}} \right)= \prod_k \mathbb{P}(A_{n_{\phi(k)}}) = \lim\limits_k\downarrow \frac{1}{4^k} = 0$$